# syntax error at line 26

Tags: python, syntax-error, quicksort

syntax error at line 26. here is the code below. not sure why I'm getting error. implementing quick sort in python

'''quick sort'''

```
def quicksort(arr, size):
    partition(arr, size)

def partition(arr, size):
    if size <= 1:
        return

    left = 0
    right = size - 1
    pivot = arr[size/2]

    while left < right:
        while arr[left] < pivot:
            left += 1
        while arr[right] > pivot:
            right -= 1

        temp = arr[left]
        arr[left] = arr[right]
        arr[right] = temp

    partition(arr, left)
    partition(arr[left:], len(arr[left:]) 
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,45,3,5,4,6]  
quicksort(arr, len(arr))
```

Comment: Add a `)` after `partition(arr[left:], len(arr[left:])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
partition(arr[left:], len(arr[left:]) 
                                     ↑
```

You're missing one `)`. Using an IDE will really help you to find little problem like this one.

Note that your code suffers from more problems, they are unrelated to the syntax error you're getting.

General note: Please make more efforts next time when you post a question, post the exact error and try to explain in your own words what problems do you have so you can get better and sooner help. Posting the error in the title and the function in the body of the question isn't really a good way of asking.

Comment: "Note that your code suffers from more problems, they are unrelated to the syntax error you're getting."

Comment: thanks for the comment Maroun...Yes, there are implementation errors in the code. I'm implementing quicksort in python but even after removing the syntax error I'm not able to get the sorted list back. Any idea, where I'm getting wrong in my implementation? or shall I create a new question for that?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parentheses on line 26.

```
partition(arr[left:], len(arr[left:])
```

should be:

```
partition(arr[left:], len(arr[left:]))
```